# trigger compiling error in sqldeveloper with oracle11g

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have been studying triggers from
[ http://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_triggers.htm][1]
 with sqldeveloper and I connected Oracle 11g database. I created customers table successfully. But when I tried to create trigger as :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER display_salary_changes
BEFORE DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON customers
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.ID > 0)
DECLARE
   sal_diff number;
BEGIN
   sal_diff := :NEW.salary  - :OLD.salary;
   dbms_output.put_line('Old salary: ' || :OLD.salary);
   dbms_output.put_line('New salary: ' || :NEW.salary);
   dbms_output.put_line('Salary difference: ' || sal_diff);
END;
```

I get these errors:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER display_salary_changes
BEFORE DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON customers
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.ID > 0)
  DECLARE
   sal_diff number
Error report -
SQL Command: trıgger DISPLAY_SALARY_CHANGES
Failed: Warning: yürütme uyarı ile tamamlandı

Error starting at line : 7 in command -
BEGIN
    sal_diff := :NEW.salary  - :OLD.salary;
    dbms_output.put_line('Old salary: ' || :OLD.salary);
    dbms_output.put_line('New salary: ' || :NEW.salary);
    dbms_output.put_line('Salary difference: ' || sal_diff);
END;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 2, column 5:
PLS-00201: identifier 'SAL_DIFF' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 3, column 60:
PLS-00487: Invalid reference to variable 'SQLDEVBIND1Z_2'
ORA-06550: line 3, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 4, column 60:
PLS-00487: Invalid reference to variable 'SQLDEVBIND1Z_1'
ORA-06550: line 4, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 5, column 51:
PLS-00201: identifier 'SAL_DIFF' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 5, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

What is wrong with this create trigger block?

Comment: Your error stack doesn't seem to jive with the code you've posted.  Is there anything else in your SQL Developer window other than the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement?

Comment: same trigger working in my pc with Oracle Database 11g version 11.2.0.4.0

Comment: When I create trigger as a new trigger like this : http://imgur.com/axdMCmC it is compiled automatically without giving any error. But when I create the trigger in a .sql file I get errors when I tired to run the block like this : http://imgur.com/ubwTCig. I could not understand.Thanks for helping.

Comment: Did you try removing the semi-colon and adding one of these:END /

Comment: I did but as I just learned it is related with the version of the SQLDeveloper, it is incompatible with my own language and somehow it confuses when I try to create trigger. When I change the version the error is removed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the same "Securing Literals" feature as described here
http://krisrice.io/2015-09-11-sqlcl-more-secure-now-with-rest/